# Перенос git-репозитория

Tags: git, git-push

Есть некоторый репозиторий с ветками `master` и `develop`:

```
git@git.test.com:my-repo-a.git
```

Есть также пустой репозиторий

```
git@git.test.com:my-repo-b.git
```

Как полностью перенести репозиторий `a` в `b`?
Под полностью подразумевается, что должны сохраниться все ветки и все коммиты.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
git clone --bare git@git.test.com:my-repo-a.git
git fetch origin
git remote add new-origin git@git.test.com:my-repo-b.git
git push --mirror new-origin
git remote rm origin
git remote rename new-origin origin
```

**Источник:** https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/moving-git-repository-new-server/

**Updated:** поправил с учётом комментариев

Comment: первой командой стоило добавить `$ git clone --bare git@git.test.com:my-pepo-a.git .`

Comment: и вместо двух команд `push` можно было использовать одну, с опцией `--mirror`: `$ git push --mirror new-origin`. она отправит все указатели — и ветки и метки.

Comment: А [для чего нужен bare](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571559/178988)? // + @alexanderbarakin

Comment: @Qwertiy, без `--bare`, **помимо** копирования содержимого хранилища, из него будет ещё локально распаковано содержимое ветки, являющейся текущей. для решения задачи, оозвученной в вопросе, эта операция (распаковка) не требуется.

Comment: вроде после первого шага - перед fetch нужно перейти в скаченную директорию

Comment: @batman ну это очевидно :) здесь показаны только команды гита

Answer (score 4):

если на целевом сервере есть возможность выполнять команды оболочки от имени пользователя, которому принадлежит каталог с хранилищем (в вопросе для иллюстрации указан пользователь *git*), то можно обойтись без копирования хранилища с исходного сервера на локальный компьютер, а затем на целевой сервер.

1. сделайте текущим каталог с целевым хранилищем:

   ```
   $ cd /путь/к/my-repo-b.git
   ```
2. от имени пользователя, которому принадлежит этот каталог, подключите исходное хранилище под каким-нибудь именем, например, `copy`:

   ```
   $ git remote add --mirror=fetch copy url-исходного-хранилища
   ```
3. скопируйте информацию:

   ```
   $ git remote update copy
   ```

---

всё. при желании можно удалить ссылку на исходное-хранилище:

```
$ git remote remove copy
```

---

если у пользователя, которому принадлежит каталог с хранилищем, не разрешён запуск интерактивной оболочки, но у вас есть возможность выполнять команды от имени пользователя *root*, перечисленное выше можно сделать и от имени *root-а*, но по завершении, не меняя текущего каталога, надо установить всем файлам/каталогам такого же владельца и группу, как и у текущего каталога, с помощью, например, такой команды (естественно, от того же имени):

```
$ chown -R --reference=. .
```

---

а если и исходный и целевой сервер — это одна и та же машина, то вместо всего вышеперечисленного можно просто скопировать файлы:

```
$ cp -a /путь/к/my-repo-a.git/* /путь/к/my-repo-b.git/
```

Answer (score 2):

Перенос существующего репозитория на удаленный сервер:

```
cd existing_repo
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin git@git.test.com:my-repo-b.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

Comment: А в чём разница по сравнению с `git push --mirror` из принятого ответа?

Comment: А, уже прочитал там в комментах, что это то же самое.