# Для чего нужен флаг bare

Tags: git, git-clone, git-init

Для чего нужен флаг `--bare` при клонировании/создании репозитория?

Что он даёт [при переносе репозитория](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571083/178988)?

Comment: В документации разве не понятно написано?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какие основные задачи bare репозитория?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542391/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8-bare-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: @Roman, ага, как-то непонятно.

Comment: @AK, не дубликат - там ничего нет про clone. Да и вообще, хотелось бы больше примеров, в каких случаях оно нужно и что именно в них даёт.

Comment: Плюсую. Почитал ссылку - нифига не понял. Итого тут уже почти на 60 тыщ репы непоняток)

Comment: Да нет особой особой разницы между init или clone. Bare -- это всё вокруг папки .git и рабочего каталога крутится.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### совсем короткая формулировка

вот вам надо, допустим, скопировать архив с одного сервера на другой, и вам дают инструкцию:

1. скопируйте архив с сервера1 на локальную машину
2. распакуйте архив
3. скопируйте архив на сервер2

а зачем, спрашивается, здесь нужен пункт 2, про распаковку архива??? не нужен. вот и при копировании хранилища аналогичная ситуация — а зачем извлекать из хранилища содержимое *рабочего каталога*? не нужно. для этого и пригодится опция `--bare`.

### более обстоятельный ответ

начать надо, пожалуй, с иллюстрации того, что, собственно, представляет собой git-хранилище (часто используется термин «git-репозиторий»).

вот оно, свежесозданное хранилище, не отслеживающее (пока) ни одного файла, но уже содержащее 9 каталогов и 13 файлов (в разных версиях и сборках программы *git* конкретные цифры могут, конечно, слегка отличаться), необходимый минимум, который позволит программе *git* начать отслеживание файлов вашего проекта (ну, почти необходимый — без файлов с примерами из каталога `hooks` можно было бы и обойтись):

```
$ tree -F
.
├── branches/
├── config*
├── description
├── HEAD
├── hooks/
│   ├── applypatch-msg.sample*
│   ├── commit-msg.sample*
│   ├── post-update.sample*
│   ├── pre-applypatch.sample*
│   ├── pre-commit.sample*
│   ├── prepare-commit-msg.sample*
│   ├── pre-push.sample*
│   ├── pre-rebase.sample*
│   └── update.sample*
├── info/
│   └── exclude
├── objects/
│   ├── info/
│   └── pack/
└── refs/
    ├── heads/
    └── tags/

9 directories, 13 files
```

эти файлы и каталоги появятся в текущем (изначально пустом) каталоге после выполнения команды:

```
$ git init --bare
```

а если опустить опцию `--bare`, все они будут «спрятаны под капотом» — программа *git* создаст их не в текущем каталоге, а в подкаталоге `.git` (точка в начале имени служит для того, чтобы в unix-подобной операционной системе этот подкаталог по умолчанию не показывался при получении листинга каталога).

«спрятаны» они будут не только «для эстетики» и не только потому, что эти «внутренние потроха» для «обычного» пользователя программы *git* представляют мало интереса. основная цель — «освободить» текущий каталог под собственно файлы (и каталоги) вашего проекта. в этом случае он (текущий каталог) будет выполнять функции *рабочего каталога* (*working tree* в оригинальной документации, другой нередко встречающийся перевод — *рабочая копия*).

---

если при хранилище имеется *рабочий каталог*, то такое хранилище называют «не-bare-хранилищем», или «хранилищем с рабочим каталогом», а чаще, для краткости — просто «хранилищем». а если *рабочего каталога* нет, то такое хранилище называют «bare-хранилищем» (дословно — «голым»).

---

а какая польза от такого «bare-хранилища»? какой практический смысл в нём? что с ним можно сделать?

ну, с точки зрения «конечного» пользователя (чаще всего — программиста) пользы, действительно, мало, ведь не видно же файлов/каталогов проекта. а вот с точки зрения программы *git* — это полноценное хранилище, которое можно клонировать, делать из него *pull-ы*, а в него — *push-ы*. именно в таком виде (без *рабочего каталога*) располагаются хранилища на таких серверах, как github.com, bitbucket.org и тому подобных. программа *git* легко может извлечь и отобразить любую информацию из такого хранилища: историю коммитов, листинг файлов проекта, содержимое любого из файлов проекта в том состоянии, как он выглядел после любого из коммитов, и так далее и тому подобное.

---

опцию `--bare` можно использовать и вместе с командой `clone`: в этом случае в текущем (или указанном) каталоге будет сначала создан «костяк» хранилища (состоящий из вышеперечисленного набора 13-ти файлов и 9-ти каталогов), который будет наполнен информацией из клонируемого хранилища (в основном это коснётся каталога `objects` — именно в нём хранятся git-объекты: коммиты, деревья и блобы).

а вот если выполнять команду `clone` **без** этой опции, то, во-первых, хранилище будет помещено в подкаталог `.git`, а не непосредственно в текущий каталог, а во-вторых, **после** наполнения хранилища будут **дополнительно** извлечены в текущий каталог все файлы и каталоги проекта.

---

стоит ещё отметить, что признак хранилища — «bare/не-bare» — хранится в файле `config` внутри хранилища в виде строчки `bare=true` или `bare=false` в секции `[core]`.

---

ах, да, совсем забыл:

> Что он (подразумевается опция `--bare`) даёт при [переносе репозитория](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571083/178988)?

из вышеизложенного, надеюсь, стало понятно, что эта опция в случае переноса хранилища с одного сервера на другой позволяет не делать ненужную (в данном случае) работу: сэкономить такты процессора (на извлечение файлов/каталогов проекта), сэкономить ресурс винчестера на излишних операциях чтения/записи, сберечь немного электроэнергии, и, в конечном счёте, отдалить тепловую смерть вселенной. это же реальная цель существования человечества, верно?