# Как создать удаленный репозиторий git?

Tags: git, git-remote

На удаленной машине в непустом каталоге сделал

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Вроде бы все хорошо, даже на локальной машине получилось клонировать через ssh, но вот пушить я в него не могу:

```
push master to origin/master was rejected by remote
```

Везде говорят про необходимость создания bare репозитория, я делал

```
git clone --bare rep_name rep_name.git
```

Репозиторий создавался, я его даже удаленно мог клонировать, но он был пуст и что с ним делать дальше я не знаю.

Как сделать так, чтоб я мог работать со своим удаленным репозиторием?

Comment: На удалённой машине удалите рабочую копию *cd repo; mv .git ../repo.git; cd ..; rm -rf repo*. Потом промаркируйте этот репозиторий как bare. На локальной машине клонируйте как обычно. Disclaimer: перед тем как делать, создайте backup.

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571584/178576) и [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/542434/178576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как у меня все получилось:

Чтоб создать удаленный репозиторий и иметь возможность вносить в него изменения нужно создать пустой репозиторий командой

```
git init --bare
```

Потом этот репозиторий клонировать и уже в клона вносить изменения, там можно делать коммиты и пушить их в основной bare репозиторий, он не будет хранить непосредственно распакованные файлы, но им можно будет оперировать как любым другим репозиторием.